# prevent ggplot barplot moving along x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data frame, long formatted, which i want to barplot:

```
        seccion             variable value
1        1                   pt     2
2        2                   pt     0
3        3                   pt     3
4        4                   pt     0
5        1 movimiento_ciudadano     5
6        2 movimiento_ciudadano     2
7        3 movimiento_ciudadano     7
8        4 movimiento_ciudadano     4
9        1        nueva_alianza   752
10       2        nueva_alianza    51
11       3        nueva_alianza   248
12       4        nueva_alianza    25
13       1               morena   114
14       2               morena    21
15       3               morena    24
16       4               morena    19
```

When I run this line

```
    ggplot(molten_, aes(x=seccion, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + facet_wrap(~seccion) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","orange", "turquoise", "tomato3",
                              "gray60","gray40","purple","blue", 
                              "green", "gray40")) +
  labs(title="acajete")
```

the bars are moving along x axis, like this:

[image]

I think it's something about the mapping of x, how can I avoid this?

Comment: `facet_wrap(~seccion, scales='free_x')`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you use `seccion` for both the x-variable and the facet. So when the variable = 1 it appears in facet 1, variable = 2 is in facet 2 and so on.

I think you want to use `variable` for the x-variable and `seccion` for the facets. When I do that using your example data, I get this:

```
ggplot(molten_, aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable)) + 
  facet_wrap(~seccion) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]